# NZEC in python on spoj for AP2

Tags: python-2.7, return, return-value

I wrote the following two codes

### FCTRL2.py

```
import sys;
def fact(x):
    res = 1
    for i in range (1,x+1):
        res=res*i
    return res;

t = int(raw_input());
for i in range (0,t):
    print fact(int(raw_input()));
```

and

### AP2.py

```
import sys;

t = int(raw_input());
for i in range (0,t):
    x,y,z = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
    n = (2*z)/(x+y)
    d = (y-x)/(n-5)
    a = x-(2*d)
    print n
    for j in range(0,n):
        sys.stdout.write(a+j*d)
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
    print' '
```

FCTRL2.py is accepted on spoj whereas AP2.py gives NZEC error. Both work fine on my machine and i do not find much difference with regard to returning values from both. Please explain what is the difference in both and how do i avoid NZEC error for AP2.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be extra white spaces in the input. A good problem setter would ensure that the input satisfies the specified format. But since spoj allows almost anyone to add problems, issues like this sometimes arise. One way to mitigate white space issues is to read the input at once, and then tokenize it.

```
import sys;   # Why use ';'? It's so non-pythonic.

inp = sys.stdin.read().split()    # Take whitespaces as delimiter
t = int(inp[0])
readAt = 1
for i in range (0,t):
    x,y,z = map(int,inp[readAt:readAt+3])    # Read the next three elements
    n = (2*z)/(x+y)
    d = (y-x)/(n-5)
    a = x-(2*d)
    print n
    #for j in range(0,n):
    #    sys.stdout.write(a+j*d)
    #    sys.stdout.write(' ')
    #print ' '
    print ' '.join([str(a+ti*d) for ti in xrange(n)]) # More compact and faster
    readAt += 3   # Increment the index from which to start the next read
```

Answer (score 0):

The n in line 10 can be a float, the range function expects an integer. Hence the program exits with an exception.

I tested this on Windows with values:

```
>ap2.py
23
4 7 9
1.6363636363636365
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\martin\ap2.py", line 10, in <module>
    for j in range(0,n):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Input will always ensure n to be integer.